# Button Feedback color python in maya?

Tags: python, maya

I'm a beginner to python. I'm creating a UI that select objects in my scene. 
I want the button to change color when it's clicked from default gray to white and remain white and back to gray when deselected.
Kindly make it simple for me to understand,Thanks!
The button code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def MyWindow():    
    #delete existing window
    if cmds.window("GuiWindow", exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI("GuiWindow")
    #create window
    window = cmds.window("GuiWindow", title = "Object Selecter",\
         w = 400, h = 600, sizeable = False, mxb = False)
    column = cmds.columnLayout(w = 400, h = 600)
    form = cmds.formLayout(w = 400, h = 600)
    #background image
    BGimage = cmds.internalVar(upd = True)+"icons/picker_bg01.jpg"
    cmds.image(w = 400, h = 600, image = BGimage)
    #create button
    object1 = cmds.button(label = "", w = 100, h = 50, \
        bgc = [0.5,0.5,0.5],command=lambda x: cmds.select("object1"))
    # More buttons to be created
    cmds.formLayout(form, e = True,af = (object1,"top",100))
    cmds.formLayout(form, e = True,af = (object1,"left",150))
MyWindow()

cmds.showWindow(window)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit your UI elements by using the command with the argument *edit* set to true. e.g.

```
button  = cmds.button(bgc=[.5, .5, .5])
cmds.button(button, edit=True, bgc=[1,1,1])
```

In your case, you can create a button command and switch the color there. To make it simpler you can even get the current value with the **query** argument set to true.

```
currentColor = cmds.button(button, query=True, bgc=True)
```

This way you can check the current color and switch if needed to the other one.

Comment: Thanks haggi krey for your answer,Just awesome. Okay so buttons will used to select objects and the idea is when a button click (object is selected) the button color should switch to white automatically to indicate that object is selected and when the object is deselected the button should switch back to default color to indicate that objecting is no longer selected. More like a button color feedback. How do I achieve this? Thanks again!

Comment: you should put a cmds.scriptJob while your ui is running to change the color of the button if a certain element is selected. Do you have some code to show ?

Comment: Hello DrWeeny, here is the code so far. Kindly  help with the scriptjob as simple as possible and you can attach the scriptjob to the code so I know how it how it all come together that will be a big help.Thanks

Comment: ill try to do this tomorrow ! I dont have maya at home